# Why does my equal method always return false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I just started learning classes in python and I'm trying to implement an array based list. This is my class and the init constructor.

```
class List:

def __init__(self,max_capacity=50):
    self.array=build_array(max_capacity)
    self.count=0
```

However, I wrote a method **equals** that returns true if the list equals another. However, it always return false. And yes my append method is working.

```
 def __eq__(self,other):
    result=False
    if self.array==other:
        result=True
    else:
        result=False
    return result
```

This is how I tested it but it return false?

```
a_list=List()
b_list=[3,2,1]
a_list.append(3)
a_list.append(2)
a_list.append(1)
print(a_list==b_list)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

#### EDIT:

After all the helpful suggestions, I figured out I have to iterate through other and a_list and check the elements.

Comment: What's the content of `b_list`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add b_list.Edited.

Comment: You are trying to determine if `self == other` by checking if `self.array == other`. At the very least, you probably want to compare `self.array == other.array`. `result` is an unnecessary temporary variable; just use `return self.array == other.array`. However, it's not safe to assume that `other` is also an instance of `List` just because that's the intended use case.

Comment: Show your append method...

Answer (score 3):

`__eq__`, for any class, should handle three cases:

1. `self` and `other` are the same object
2. `self` and `other` are compatible instances (up to duck-typing: they don't need to be instances of the same class, but should support the same interface as necessary)
3. `self` and `other` are *not* comparable.

Keeping these three points in mind, define `__eq__` as

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self is other:
        return True
    try:
        return self.array == other.array
    except AttributeError:
        # other doesn't have an array attribute,
        # meaning they can't be equal
        return False
```

Note this assumes that a `List` instance should compare as equal to another object as long as both objects have equal `array` attributes (whatever that happens to mean). If that isn't what you want, you'll have to be more specific in your question.

---

One final option is to fall back to `other == self` to see if type of `other` knows how to compare itself to your `List` class. Equality should be symmetric, so `self == other` and `other == self` should produce the same value if, indeed, the two values can be compared for equality.

```
except AttributeError:
    return other == self
```

Of course, you need to be careful that this doesn't lead to an infinite loop of `List` and `type(other)` repeatedly deferring to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the array embedded in your instance (`self.array`) to the entirety of the other object. This will not work well.

You need to compare `self.array` to `other.array` and/or convert both objects to the same type before comparing. You probably also need to specify what it means to compare two arrays (i.e., you want a single boolean value that indicates whether all elements are equal, not an array of boolean values for each element).

For the code below, I assume you are using a `numpy` `ndarray` for `self.array`. If not, you could write your own `array_equal` that will convert `other` to an array, then compare the lengths of the arrays, then return `(self.array==other_as_array).all()`.

If you want to test for strict equality between the objects (same types, same values), you could use this:

```
from numpy import array_equal

import numpy as np
class List
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, List) and array_equal(self.array, other.array)
```

If you just want to check for equality of the items in the list, regardless of the object type, then you could do this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, List):
        return array_equal(array, other.array)
    else:
        return array_equal(self.array, other)
```